brew update takes forever updating watchman
when i update brew with brew update -d it stops at building watchman the builds consumes 90% of cpu and does not finish
any hit what to do?
        ==> Upgrading watchman
      4.9.0 -> 2024.05.06.00
   .......
   
    
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading boost
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading boost
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading boost
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fb303
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fb303
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fb303
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fbthrift
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fbthrift
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fbthrift
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fmt
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fmt
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading fmt
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading folly
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading folly
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading folly
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading gflags
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading gflags
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading gflags
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading glog
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading glog
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading glog
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libevent
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libevent
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libevent
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libsodium
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libsodium
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading libsodium
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    ==> Installing dependencies for watchman: llvm and rust
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading llvm
    ==> Installing watchman dependency: llvm
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading llvm
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python-setuptools
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python-setuptools
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromPathLoader): loading /Users/simoncigoj/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api-source/Homebrew/homebrew-core/21ce6eaf90e03ad0034001cdf77f4cd5ee428231/Formula/llvm.rb
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python-setuptools
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pcre2
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading pkg-config
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python-setuptools
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading cmake
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ninja
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading swig
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading mpdecimal
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading ca-certificates
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading openssl@3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading readline
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading sqlite
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading xz
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading python@3.12
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading z3
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading lz4
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb (Formulary::FromAPILoader): loading zstd
    /usr/bin/env tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/simoncigoj/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/63b3e761fd7e13d3e0b7cf440aafd0998166526768b568c4c82c10467f39427d--llvm-project-18.1.7.src.tar.xz --directory /private/tmp/homebrew-unpack20240610-89034-du0aze
    /usr/bin/env cp -pR /private/tmp/homebrew-unpack20240610-89034-du0aze/llvm-project-18.1.7.src/. /private/tmp/llvm-20240610-89034-jvaccu/llvm-project-18.1.7.src
    ==> cmake -G Ninja .. -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra;lld;mlir;polly;lldb -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=compiler-rt;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;openmp -DLLVM_POLLY_LINK_INTO_TOOLS=ON -DLLVM_BUILD_EXTERNAL_COMPILER_RT=ON -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=ON
    ==> cmake --build .


Were you able to fix this issue?
